# Can't I use pointer to the type of interface in Go?

Tags: go

I write the code with DI as follows. There are 2 code. One is for `use case` and other is `controller` that depend on that `use case`.

- Use Case

```golang
package usecase

import "fmt"

type Interface interface {
    Echo() string
}

type UseCase struct {}

func (u *UseCase) Echo() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("this is usecase!")
}
```

- Controller

```golang
package controller

import (
    "my-project/usecase"
)

type Controller struct {
    usecase *usecase.Interface
}

func NewController(useCase *usecase.Interface) *Controller {
    return &Controller{
        usecase: useCase,
    }
}

func (s *Controller) Hello() {
    result := s.usecase.Echo()
    println(result)
}
```

However, in the controller the following error message was displayed.

`Unresolved reference 'Echo'`

The type of field `usecase` in the controller structure `Controller` is `*usecase.Interface`. (pointer)
The reason is that the `Echo()` method of `UseCase`, which implements the interface, is a pointer receiver.

I can't use a pointer to the interface as follows?

```golang
type Controller struct {
    usecase *usecase.Interface
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to an interface? There's practically never any reason for this.

Comment: The reason is that `func (u *UseCase) Echo() string` is pointer receiver. I'm planning on add the logic to update field of struct `UseCase`. Even if so, I shouldn't use pointer?

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Pointer receiver or not is irrelevant. You must use the raw interface value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
type Controller struct {
    usecase usecase.Interface
}

func NewController(useCase usecase.Interface) *Controller {
    return &Controller{
        usecase: useCase,
    }
}

func (s *Controller) Hello() {
    result := s.usecase.Echo()
    println(result)
}
```

There's almost never any reason to use a pointer to an interface.  The only time you would want a pointer to an interface, is when you need to set an interface value, which is passed as a function argument.  i.e.:

```golang
var x SomeInterface
SetX(&x)
```